# How to find the maximum and minimum value of ranges that are in another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created VBA code that automatically copies data from other workbooks, based on a certain date and portfolio, to the active sheet.

I have successfully copied all the information I need, however, I am missing 2 parts.

I want to find the minimum value in a certain range in the other workbook (that I open using the `For` loop) and copy it to my active sheet.
Same goes for the maximum of another range in the opened workbook.

Following is the code I have so far. Somehow the

```
Application.Max(Workbooks(portfolioName).Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("J16:J1000"))
```

functions are simply returning a value of zero.

```
Option Explicit

Function MatchHeader(strSearch As String) As Long
Dim myRight As Long, Colcount As Long

myRight = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Colcount = 1 To myRight 
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Colcount) = strSearch Then
        MatchHeader = Colcount
        Exit For          
    End If
Next Colcount
End Function

Sub StressTest()

Dim index As Integer
Dim dateColumn As Integer
Dim portfolioDate As String
Dim portfolioName As Variant
Dim ParametricVar As Double
Dim AuM As Double
Dim PreviousVar As Double
Dim PreviousAuM As Double

Dim strPath As String
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sheet = ActiveSheet

portfolioDate = InputBox("Please enter date under the following form : YYYY-MM", "Date at the time of Stress Test", "Type Here")
Debug.Print "InputBox provided value is: " & portfolioDate

For index = 26 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row    
  dateColumn = MatchHeader(portfolioDate)
  portfolioName = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & index & "").Value

  strPath = "G:\Risk\Risk Reports\VaR-Stress test\" & portfolioDate & "\" & portfolioName & ""

  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

  ParametricVar = Workbooks(portfolioName).Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("B19")
  AuM = Workbooks(portfolioName).Worksheets("Holdings - Main View").Range("E11")
  PreviousVar = sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 7).Value
  PreviousAuM = sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 9).Value

  sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn).Value = ParametricVar / AuM
  sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 2).Value = AuM
  sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 1).Value = (ParametricVar - PreviousVar) / PreviousVar
  sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 3).Value = (AuM - PreviousAuM) / PreviousAuM

  sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 5).Value = Application.Min(Workbooks(portfolioName).Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("P11:AA11"))
  sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 6).Value = Application.Max(Workbooks(portfolioName).Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("J16:J1000"))

  wb.Close Savechanges:=False

Next index

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify & Try:

```
 Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Dim Max As Double, Min As Double

    'Set the workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("Book1")
    'Set the worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Set range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A10")

    Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
    Debug.Print Max
    Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
    Debug.Print Min

End Sub
```

Comment: I have added this however it is giving me a type 91 error

```
VaRcomp = wb.Worksheets("VaR Comparison")

rng1 = VaRcomp.Range("P11:AA11")

rng2 = VaRcomp.Range("J16:J1000")

sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng1)
sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng2)
```

Comment: at this line
VaRcomp = wb.Worksheets("VaR Comparison")

Comment: Create a new module, paste my code, change the names of `wb` & `ws` and tell me if you get the same error

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers was very good.

If you're looking to just add a few lines to yours you can try for the minimum:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(R[1]C[-9]:R[37]C[-2])"
Range("CELL YOU WANT IT IN").Select
```

And for max:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(R[1]C[-11]:R[37]C[-4])"
Range("CELL YOU WANT IT IN").Select
```